# How to jasmine test with createSpyObj that has class properties defined as spys

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jasmine

I'm trying to mock a service that provides a few properties as set only. The documentation [Here](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.5/jasmine.html) seems to indicate that there should be a way to create this spy object with properties being spied/mocked but I've been getting errors indicating the value is undefined.

I'd like to be able to tell what the value of these properties have been set to during testing and that they can be tested for get only and set only.

I haven't been able to find any great examples of how this is supposed to be used. I tried passing in an array of string as the docs seemed to indicate.

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    taskServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj<TaskService>(
      ["getTasks"],
      ["searchString", "searchTaskStatus"]
    );

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [SearchTaskComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: TaskService, useValue: taskServiceMock }],
    }).compileComponents();
  }))
```

I've also tried passing spy objects into the properties field

```
const spySearchString = spyOnProperty(taskServiceMock, "searchString", "set");
const spyTaskStatus = spyOnProperty(taskServiceMock, "searchTaskStatus", "set");

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    taskServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj<TaskService>(
      ["getTasks"],
      [spySearchString, spySearchTaskStatus]
    );

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [SearchTaskComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: TaskService, useValue: taskServiceMock }],
    }).compileComponents();
  }))
```

Service Code being mocked by the component

```
  private _searchStatus: TaskStatus;
  private _searchString: string;

  set searchString(search: string) {
    this._searchString = search;
  }

  set searchTaskStatus(status: TaskStatus) {
    this._searchStatus = status;
  }
```

In both cases I'm getting a error indicating the module won't compile so I'm testing against an undefined value.
Jasmine Version **3.5**
Angular Version **9.0.2**

Answer (score 0):

If the service is indeed that simple, I would just provide it and not worry about mocking it.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [SearchTaskComponent],
      providers: [TaskService],
    }).compileComponents();
```

If that is not what you want, try using `useClass` instead.

(Mock is the same as what you showed me)

```
class MockTaskService {
  private _searchStatus: TaskStatus;
  private _searchString: string;

  set searchString(search: string) {
    this._searchString = search;
  }

  set searchTaskStatus(status: TaskStatus) {
    this._searchStatus = status;
  }
}
......
let taskService: any;
...
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [SearchTaskComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: TaskService, useClass: MockTaskService}],
    }).compileComponents();

taskService = TestBed.inject(TaskService); // get a handle on it
```